# Heat of the sun

Tags: sources-mekorot

In ספר הברית השלם, authored by
פינחס אליהו בן מאיר הורביץ, he writes that there are akhronim who say that the sun possesses no heat ([p. 50](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43670&st=&pgnum=50&hilite=)):

> ושקר אמרו שהמה מורכבים מארבעה יסודות וגשמיים כמו עולם הזה, כי איך אפשר
> להיות בני-אדם כמונו יושבי חמה וחום השמש לא ישרוף אותם, וכל חום בצאן
> ובקר ויחיו? ואם **אין חום בשמש, כדעת האחרונים**, איך לא יעורו עיניהם
> מראות בתעצמות זוהר של המאור הגדול הזה תמיד, ואנו לא נוכל להביט בו רגע
> אחד? או איך אפשר להיות בני-אדם יושבי שבתאי ולפני קרתו מי יעמד?

Is there a source for this?

Comment: [Hard to believe](https://www.sefaria.org/Psalms.19.6?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Psalms.19.7.2&lang2=bi)

Comment: I agree that it's difficult,  yet seeing it written in a reputable book leads one to think...

Comment: וחם השמש ונמס Beshalach

Comment: So how would you explain the phrase "אין חום בשמש"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a once extant view in the medieval era. In the Foundations of Modern Science in the Medieval Era (pp. 109-110) Edward Grant explains:

> The celestial spheres, as we saw, were assumed to be composed of an
> incorruptible ether whose properties contrasted radically with those
> of the incessantly changing four elements of the terrestrial region.
> In Aristotle's scheme, change was unrealizable in the heavens because
> of an absence of contrary qualities, so that no pair of such qualities
> could act on the same celestial body or in the same portion of
> celestial ether. But if the heavenly ether lacked contrary qualities,
> why did natural philosophers and astrologers attribute contrary
> qualities to celestial bodies? For example, why did they describe
> Saturn as cold and dry, Mars as hot and dry, the Moon as cold and wet,
> and so on for the other planets? If these qualities were really absent
> from celestial bodies, why did astrologers and natural philosophers
> speak as if they were present? The standard medieval reply to such a
> question would have been that **the celestial ether possesses these
> qualities only virtually (virtualiter), not formally (formaliter), or
> actually. That is, a celestial body is said to "possess" qualities
> like hotness or coldness only in the sense that it can somehow cause
> changes in the hotness or coldness in bodies below the Moon, even
> though that celestial body does not actually possess the qualities
> that it allegedly produces in terrestrial bodies.** To say, for example,
> that Saturn is cold is not to say that the quality "coldness" actually
> inheres in Saturn's ethereal matter - indeed, it does not - but rather
> that Saturn has the capacity to produce the effect of coldness in the
> terrestrial region. Again, **the Sun is not actually hot, but it has the
> capacity to cause hotness in objects in the terrestrial region.**

This notion is similarly found in the [Kuzari (4:3)](https://www.sefaria.org/Kuzari.4.3?lang=bi&lookup=%D7%9E%D6%B0%D7%97%D6%B7%D7%9E%D6%BC%D6%B5&with=Lexicon&lang2=en):

> הַשֶּׁמֶשׁ – נִרְאֶה אוֹתָהּ עִגּוּל פָּשׁוּט כְּשִׁעוּר הַצִּנָּה
> וּבְתָאֳרָה: מַזְהִירָה, חַמָּה, נָחָה, וְהַשֵּׂכֶל גּוֹזֵר כִּי הוּא
> כַדּוּר גָּדוֹל מִכַּדּוּר הָאָרֶץ בְּמֵאָה וְשִׁשִּׁים וְשֵׁשׁ
> פְּעָמִים, וְ**שֶׁאֵינָהּ חַמָּה** וְלֹא נָחָה, אַךְ הִיא מִתְנוֹעַעַת
> שְׁתֵּי תְנוּעוֹת מִתְהַפְּכוֹת
>
> Another instance is offered by the sun, which we see as a round, flat
> body, resembling a shield and giving forth light and heat, being in
> repose. Reason considers it to be a globe a hundred and sixty-six
> times larger than the globe of the earth, **neither hot** nor immovable,
> but moving in two opposite directions...

The [Ibn Ezra (Exodus 33:21)](https://www.daat.ac.il/daat/olam_hatanah/mefaresh.asp?book=2&perek=33&mefaresh=ezra) wrote:

> ו**אל יעלה על לבך** כי הארבעה תולדות הם בשמים. ו**יש חום בשמש** וקור בלבנה
> ובשבתי חלילה חלילה כי הבריות העליונות נכבדות הן. ועליהם כתוב: כי הוא
> ציווה ונבראו ויעמידם לעד לעולם חוק נתן ולא יעבר.
>
> **Don't let it occur to you that** the four elements [which are constantly subject to change] are to be found in the heavens. And that
> **there is heat in the sun** and coldness in the moon and Saturn, heaven forfend, for the celestial creations are glorious. And about
> them Scripture states "He hath also established them for ever and
> ever; He hath made a decree which shall not be transgressed."

Presumably R. Horowitz and any Aharonim he is citing are referring to this scientific model.

Comment: My only problem with this response is that rav horowitz mentions "אחרונים" which would imply other rabbis; as opposed to philosphers or scientists where I presume he would use a different language to refer to them.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a quote from the Kuzari and the Ibn Ezra. I assume that any later Aharonim are repeating this view that was already in circulation during the Rishonic era. I'll continue to update if I come across additional sources.

Comment: ThanQ. I appreciate your help